# Masking a numpy array after selection with a non-numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, selection, mask

I have the following code:

```
# unicorns is a numpy array with several fields
idx = (1, 2, 3, 5, 7)
unicorns=uni[idx]
# now i have only the first, second, third, ... unicorn
print unicorns
```

However if I want to subselect this unicorn array

```
unicorns['color'=='white']['Name']
```

which should give me the names of the unicorns that are white, numpy interprets only 
the `color==white` part as `False`, which goes to 0 and it returns the first entry of my array.

How can I fix this code, so that it does what I want it to, selecting the white unicorns?

I would prefer everything stays as numpy, so I can also select other properties oft the unicorns.

**Edit**

Here is an example for the arrays:

```
    unicorns=[(1, black, 0.0, 'Pinky', 1) (2, black, 0.0, 'Winky', 1)
 (3, white, 0.0, 'Lala', 1) (4, white, 0.0, 'Merlin', 1)
 (5, black, 0.0, 'Meriva', 1) (6, white, 0.0, 'Panda', 1)]
    idx = [  0 ,  3  , 6 ]
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal version of `unicorns` that can be used to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probabply want to use is the [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function.
Use it like this:

```
    >>>unicorns=np.array([[1, "black", 0.0, 'Pinky', 1] ,
                       [2, "black", 0.0, 'Winky', 1],
                       [3, "white", 0.0, 'Lala', 1],
                       [4, "white", 0.0, 'Merlin', 1],
                       [5, "black", 0.0, 'Meriva', 1],
                       [6, "white", 0.0, 'Panda', 1]])
    >>> np.where(unicorns[:,1] == "black")
    (array([0, 1, 4]),)
    >>> unicorns[np.where(unicorns[:,1] == "black")]
    array([['1', 'black', '0.0', 'Pinky', '1'],
    ['2', 'black', '0.0', 'Winky', '1'],
    ['5', 'black', '0.0', 'Meriva', '1']], 
    dtype='|S8')
```

Comment: You're transforming the input as an array of strings... Stick with structured arrays.

Answer (score 4):

I had to modify your array a bit to make it valid Python code. If I converted it properly, then I think what you are looking for is:

```
unicorns[unicorns['color'] == 'white']['name']
```

---

```
import numpy as np

unicorns=[(1, 'black', 0.0, 'Pinky', 1), (2, 'black', 0.0, 'Winky', 1),
          (3, 'white', 0.0, 'Lala', 1), (4, 'white', 0.0, 'Merlin', 1),
          (5, 'black', 0.0, 'Meriva', 1), (6, 'white', 0.0, 'Panda', 1),
          ]
unicorns = np.array(unicorns,
                    dtype = [('id', '<i4'),
                             ('color', 'S10'),
                             ('val1', '<f4'),
                             ('name', 'S10'),
                             ('val2', '<i4')])

print(unicorns['color'] == 'white')
# [False False  True  True False  True]

print(unicorns[unicorns['color'] == 'white']['name'])
# ['Lala' 'Merlin' 'Panda']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at pandas which is really awesome for such kinds of slicing and querying operations. Your problem could be solved with it like that:

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(unicorns)

In [13]: df.columns = ['id','color','speed','name','tails']

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
  id  color speed    name tails
0  1  black   0.0   Pinky     1
1  2  black   0.0   Winky     1
2  3  white   0.0    Lala     1
3  4  white   0.0  Merlin     1
4  5  black   0.0  Meriva     1
5  6  white   0.0   Panda     1

In [16]: df[df.color == 'black']
Out[16]: 
  id  color speed    name tails
0  1  black   0.0   Pinky     1
1  2  black   0.0   Winky     1
4  5  black   0.0  Meriva     1

In [17]: df[df.color == 'black'].name
Out[17]: 
0     Pinky
1     Winky
4    Meriva
Name: name
```